# How to create red header while recording in an app

Tags: iphone

In the default Voice Recording app on the iPhone, starting to record turns the iPhone header red and starts a timer.  Is this something that we can reproduce in an app, or perhaps this is behavior that always happens when recording sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MTStatusBarOverlay on GitHub](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay).

Answer (score 0):

Also, try this one....

[Tweetbot-Like Alert Panels (Blog)](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-tweetbot-like-alertpanels/), and the repository is [MKInfoPanelDemo at Github](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKInfoPanelDemo).